# How to check which of multiple conditions is false without using multiple if statements in Python

Tags: python-2.7

I have 4 condition checks and they each may or may not fail. But if one of them fails, I want to know which particular condition has failed without using multiple `if` statements:

```
if (opts_vals['config_path'] is None or not os.path.isfile(opts_vals['config_path'])) or (opts_vals['myaccount'] is None or opts_vals['cust_account'] is None):
```

Comment: So split it out into separate tests, rather than a single line, then deal with each step separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible. you just have to retest your values, or write your test an other way, maybe something like this:

```
if opts_vals['config_path'] not None:
   if os.path.isfile(opts_vals['config_path']):
      do_stuff()
   else:
      do_stuff_failed()
else:
   do_stuff_failed()
```

Comment: i don't want to write multiple if statements. Control goes to else as soon as any of the condition fails, is it not returning the name of variable which did not match or that condition itself?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what's wrong with multiple if statements, but you can assign the result of a comparison to a variable:

```
test1 = opts_vals['config_path'] is None 
test2 = not os.path.isfile(opts_vals['config_path'])
...
```

and you can then test all the conditions together and identify which one failed:

```
if test1 or test2 or test3 or test4:
    failure = [test1, test2, test3, test4].index(True)
    do some other stuff

# failure contains 0 if test1 was True, or 1 if test2 was True, etc
# note if none of them was True then index would generate a ValueError
```